# Center of a compact convex set.

Tags: real-analysis, geometry, convex-analysis

Let $K\subset\mathbb{R}^{n}$ be a compact and convex subset of $\mathbb{R}^{n}$. We define the center of $K$, $s(K)$, as the point
\begin{equation}\nonumber
s(K) = \mu(K)^{-1}\int_{K} xd\mu
\end{equation}
I've also seen this other definition
\begin{equation}\nonumber
c(K) = \mu(K)^{-1}\int_{\mathbb{S}^{n-1}} u\cdot s_{K}(u)\mu(u),
\end{equation}
where $s_{K}$ is the support function of $K$ and $\mu$ is the Lebesgue measure over $K$ in the first equation and over $\mathbb{S}^{n-1}$ in the second equation. My question is why $s(K),c(K)\in\mathbb{R}^{n}$?.

The integral gives us real numbers, right?.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

The first integral is over $x\in K$, and $x$ is a vector, not a real.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe try to solve an explicit example like
\begin{equation}
\frac{1}{\mathrm{vol}([-1,1]^2)}\int_{[-1,1]} \int_{[-1,1]} \begin{bmatrix}x_1 \\ x_2 \end{bmatrix} dx_1 dx_2. 
\end{equation}